# TBXML - Error Handling

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Hey everbody. How can i handle a error with the TBXML? I mean, if dont find the file, or what else. Actually, my app just crashes when i turn off the server where the file is.

So, how can i handle that?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    TBXML * tbxml = [[TBXML tbxmlWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://localhost/dev/mcomm/produto.xml"]] retain];
    TBXMLElement * rootXMLElement = tbxml.rootXMLElement;



}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the error's coming from the line where you instantiate tbxml you could try wrapping it in a `@try/@catch` block:

```
TBXML *tbxml = nil;
@try {
    tbxml = [[TBXML tbxmlWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://localhost/dev/mcomm/produto.xml"]] retain];;
}
@catch (NSException *exception) {
    NSLog(@"Caught %@: %@", [exception name], [exception reason]);
}
```

Alternatively, download the XML data separately using NSURLConnection and use NSURLConnection's delegate methods to handle error conditions. On success, pass the resulting data to a constructor such as `tbxmlWithXMLData:`.

EDIT: you've commented that the line causing the problem is:

```
TBXMLElement * xmlElement = aParentXMLElement->firstChild;
```

The error you're getting is because you're trying to dereference a null pointer (`aParentXMLElement` is nil, and calling `->someMethod` on it dereferences it). So all you need there is a guard clause to check aParentXMLElement is non-null before you attempt to dereference it. Something like this:

```
if (aParentXMLElement != nil) {
    TBXMLElement * xmlElement = aParentXMLElement->firstChild;
} else {
    NSLog(@"Can't proceed: aParentXMLElement is nil");
}
```

Comment: Hey, i tried the try and catch, but without luck. And console dont gives nothing.

Comment: And it's that line that's causing the error? And not, for example, calling `.rootXMLElement` on `tbxml` when it doesn't have one?

Comment: I'm debugging, and debugger is showing to me this line: TBXMLElement * xmlElement = aParentXMLElement->firstChild;

Comment: Ah, OK - so the error is happening because you're trying to dereference a null pointer (by using ->foo on aParentXMLElement). I'll update my answer.

Comment: Yeah, this works. 

2010-11-08 13:55:50.307 mComm[3469:207] Can't proceed: aParentXMLElement is nil
Program received signal:  “EXC_BAD_ACCESS”.

But, i want to treat this error. I mean, pop up a alert and prevent of app crash and exit.